# Appearance of a tag is messed when a jQuery function reloads it's content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, django

i am trying to send the value of `categorie` to the server and based on this value it will return a list of values that i am going to put them in a menu (sub categorie) , So i used a `jQuery`  to do this job :

**The HTML code :**

```
<div class="dropdown" id="spec">
            <button  class="form-control form-white dropdown" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Catégorie
            </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu animated fadeIn scrollable-menu" role="select" aria-labelledby="dLabel" >
        {%for cat in spec%}
            <li class="animated lightSpeedIn"><a href="#"  onclick="myFunction({{cat.id}},'sel')">{{cat.categorie}}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="dropdown">
            <button  class="form-control form-white dropdown" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Sous Catégorie
            </button>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu animated fadeIn scrollable-menu" role="select" aria-labelledby="dLabel" id="replace_me" >
        {% for sspec in s_spec %}
             <li  class="animated lightSpeedIn"><a href="#"  onclick="myFunction({{sspec.id}},'prof')">{{sspec.s_categorie}}</a></li>
         {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
```

**The jQuery function :**

```
$(function(){
          $("#spec").click(function(){
               data ={ 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': "{{ csrf_token }}", 'sel':document.getElementById("sel").value }
              $("#replace_me").load( "{% url 'login.views.profsignup' %}",data);
          });
      });
```

Now the problem is when the content of `sous categorie` is loaded the css doesn't appear properly and it's a bit messed , could anyone solve this problem ?

Comment: "the css doesn't appear properly and it's a bit messed" isn't a clear problem..

Comment: i meant that the appearance of the second menu is not as expected